# Ajax.BeginForm ignores action and controller defined in parameters in MVC 5

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, ajax.beginform

I am using attribute routing for get action of the page. But when I post it, ajax form ignores action and controller which I defined in parameters and tries to post to same url with get method.

This is my get action:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
[Route("path")]
public ActionResult Action()
{
    return View();
}
```

This is my post action:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Action(Model model)
{
    return Json(true);
}
```

This is my view:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "someDiv" }))
{

    @SomeInput

    <input type="submit" value="send" />

}
```

This the generated HTML:

```
<form action="/path" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#someDiv" id="form0" method="post">        
    <input value="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

When the button is clicked. A post to domain/path is firing. Why the action I defined is ignored?

Comment: Can you post the html that is generated by your Ajax.BeginForm?  I suspect that it hasn't been able to find your route, so it has left it as blank and it will be hitting the root of your website

Comment: @Slicksim I have updated the question.

Comment: Have you defined your routing on the controller too? or just on that one action?

Comment: @Slicksim The only routing in project is the unedited default routing in RouteConfig. And I defined an attribute routing just for that action. Not controller.

Comment: what happens if you remove the [Route] and switch it for [ActionName("Path")]

Comment: @Slicksim Now I can't get page with domain/path.

Comment: I am experiencing similar behavior. In my example I have an EditorTemplate with its own Ajax.BeginForm defined. When I render that EditorTemplate from within a DisplayTemplate it overrides the child EditorTemplate's Controller destination to the one the parent DisplayTemplate uses, however it keeps the same Action.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue by adding a null RouteValues after the Controller/ Action:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", null, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "someDiv" }))
{
    @SomeInput
    <input type="submit" value="send"/>
}
```

In my example I have an EditorTemplate with its own Ajax.BeginForm defined. When I render that EditorTemplate from within a DisplayTemplate it overrides the child EditorTemplate's Controller destination to the one the parent DisplayTemplate uses, however it keeps the same Action. So it looks like, at least in my instance, the RouteValues was being overridden if not provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
  routes.MapRoute(
              name: "Any Name",
              url: "Any URL",
              defaults: new { Controller = "Your Ajax Controller Name ", action = "Your Ajax action Name" }
              );
```

Or Try This

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Add this to the last of all routes in RouteConfig.cs

Comment: if  u have used these scripts on your page then please give us the error<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

Comment: I am using jQuery and Unobtrusive Ajax but there is not any error or something. It just generating a different url than desired one.